golang gin project memory usage limit is reached and restart is required
I have a backend api docker container with golang gin. The memory limit is 8GiB and the memory used in an average of 1 day increases to 8 GiB and the container is restarted. There is a memory usage that is constantly increasing and when it reaches the limit it has to be restarted. Has anyone experienced something like this and have any information about what could be causing it?


"what could be causing it?" -- could be global variables used as data storage, or unreleased resources (e.g., unclosed files), or unmanaged/hanging goroutines, etc. To find out exactly where you're leaking memory you can use something like pprof (the linked article is old, but there's a lot of newer resources on the topic, use your favourite search engine to find them).
